# Исключение System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, winforms

При повторном открытии формы №2 (форма №2 открывается из формы №1)
вылетает исключение "Необработанное исключение типа "System.ObjectDisposedException" в System.Windows.Forms.dll
" Как с этим бороться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            butReset.Click += new System.EventHandler(butReset_Click);
            butLoad.Click += new System.EventHandler(butLoad_Click);
          
         
            pivotGridControl1.SaveLayoutToRegistry(regKey);


        }

        public string regKey = "DevExpress\\XtraPivotGrid\\Layouts\\PivotGridLayout";
        public Button butLoad = new Button();
        public Button butReset = new Button();
        ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

        public void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
             Form form = new Form();
            form.Show();
            form.Controls.Add(listBox1);
            listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "Path";
           
            listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

            butReset.Text = "Сбросить настройки";
            butReset.Location = new Point(140, 160);
            form.Controls.Add(butReset);

            butLoad.Text = "Принять";
            butLoad.Location = new Point(30, 160);
            form.Controls.Add(butLoad);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\veryutinen\Desktop", "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                var fileItem = new FileItem { Title = Path.GetFileName(f), Path = Path.GetFullPath(f) };
                listBox1.Items.Add(fileItem);
            }

        }

        private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pivotGridControl1.RestoreLayoutFromRegistry(regKey);
        }



        public void butReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            pivotGridControl1.RestoreLayoutFromRegistry(regKey);
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        }


        public void butLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<FileItem>();
            var all = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path));
            pivotGridControl1.RestoreLayoutFromXml(all);
        }


        public void pivotGridControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Когда вы закрываете форму, она диспозит все контролы, которые находятся в ее визуальном дереве, это фича. То есть, чтобы она не задиспозила нужный вам контрол, перед закрытием окна его нужно из формы выпилить.

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего понятия о том, как это сделать.

Comment: `Controls.Add` вы умеетe, а `Controls.Remove` нет? Ну вот вам [набор методов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection?view=netcore-3.0), которые умеет выполнять `ControlCollection` - ничего не напоминает? :)

Comment: например так `form.Closing += (s, e) => form.Controls.Remove(listBox1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы закрываете форму, она диспозит все контролы, которые находятся в ее визуальном дереве, это фича. То есть, чтобы она не задиспозила нужный вам контрол, перед закрытием окна его нужно из формы выпилить.

Самое простое решение вашего вопроса выглядит так:

```cs
ListBox listBox1;

public void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = new Form();
    if (listBox1 == null)
    {
        listBox1 = new ListBox();
        listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Path";
           
        listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    }
    form.Controls.Add(listBox1);
    form.Closing += (s, e) => form.Controls.Remove(listBox1);

    butReset.Text = "Сбросить настройки";
    butReset.Location = new Point(140, 160);
    form.Controls.Add(butReset);

    butLoad.Text = "Принять";
    butLoad.Location = new Point(30, 160);
    form.Controls.Add(butLoad);
    form.Show();

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\veryutinen\Desktop", "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string f in files)
    {
        var fileItem = new FileItem { Title = Path.GetFileName(f), Path = Path.GetFullPath(f) };
        listBox1.Items.Add(fileItem);
    }
}
```

Не забудьте в обработчик `butLoad_Click` добавить проверку на `null` для `listBox1`, иначе приложение вылетит с ошибкой, если обработчик будет вызван до того как будет создан `listBox1`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо)